# ReCaptcha - Could not open socket

Tags: php, forms, sockets, captcha, recaptcha

**Before I ask this question, let me mention I know there are several of the exact same questions on the site but I am afraid they can't help me out.**

Hi,

Yesterday my ReCaptcha was working fine but now it's not. I am using the library provided by Google and using the proper code. I did not change any code since yesterday so it should still work. However, when I try to submit the form now the page returns `Could not open socket`.

Edit: I just checked and `fsockopen` is enabled on my server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Changed the following:

```
define("RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER", "www.google.com");
```

to

```
define("RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER", "74.125.227.48");
```

Now it works. This is to be edited in the captcha lib php file `recaptchalib.php`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: In case you didn't notice, I am the author and replied to my own post.

Comment: i have replaced but nothing happened same error occured "Could not open socket".
i have tryed following..

    define("RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER", "www.google.com");
    define("RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER", "74.125.227.48");
    define("RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER", gethostbyname("www.google.com"));
    define("RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER", "api-verify.recaptcha.net");
    define("RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER", "128.2.186.116");
    define("RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER", gethostbyname("www.google.com"));

Comment: It works now, but I wonder how often Google changes their IP address.. It should work for some time, but it looks like a temporary solution for me. Thanks for idea, anyways ;)

Comment: @HirenKubavat try define only once comment the others

Answer (score 12):

I came into same issue, but all the alternative host names I googled already don't work.
A very good advice that helped me was from [Recaptcha google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/recaptcha/Could%2420not%2420open%2420socket%7Csort%3arelevance/recaptcha/kCdFdAyOe60/YZJO-BnUHLIJ)

Use:

```
define("RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER", gethostbyname("www.google.com"))
```

Works just fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Open your cmd and type: ping www.google.com
The google server replay: Replay from xxx.xxx.xx.xxx ...
take the ip

Edit your recaptchalib.php

At the line

> define("RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER", "www.google.com");

replace the www.google.com with the google IP address

> define("RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER", xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx);