# reCaptcha could not open socket in joomla 3.3.1 stable

Tags: php, joomla, recaptcha, joomla3.0

Before I ask this question, let me mention I know there are several of the exact same questions on the site but I am afraid they can't help me out.

I have Joomla! 3.3.1 Stable installed on my website [krackedeggs](http://krackedeggs.org/index.php/contactus). I also have configured reCaptcha with ALFcontact but when I submit the contact us form present at the above mentioned link, it gives the error `Could not open socket`. 
I have also implemented a possible solution present at [Joomla forum](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=615&t=769245) by modifying `recaptcha.php` by replacing 
`if (($fs = @fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 10)) == false )` 
with 
`if (($fs = @fsockopen(gethostbyname($host), $port, $errno, $errstr, 10)) == false )` but my problem still not resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the most stupid thing about ALFcontact is that it doesn't use built-in Joomla reCaptcha plug-in, It uses its own script recaptchalib.php. So you have to edit it by going to
to `/components/com_alfcontact` and replacing
`define("RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER", "www.google.com");` with

```
define("RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER", gethostbyname("www.google.com"));
```

Solution is already mentioned on many places on internet e.g on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055472/recaptcha-could-not-open-socket) but path to recaptchalib.php was not mentioned anywhere so most of the people went on editing recaptcha plug-in of Joomla which is perfect